# Paypal Pro Direct Payment Recurring enable in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring

I am building PHP website where payment has been made via paypal.

Client has chosen paypal pro because he requires **direct payment** (credit card payment on website only) as well as **recurring payment**.

I found out many site with information for it but did not found any PHP Demo where user can pay via credit card from website only

Do you have demo form or sample code for it. I am in search of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check this reference links. You can find the example and sample code here

```
https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_subscribe_buttons#id08ADFK0M0IT
```

Comment: Thanks for this but link 1 - I have integrated it and working fine. Link 3 also fine but I want credit card payment on website. Like there will be 2 options pay via paypal where link1 will work and for another option via cc it will rest on website for payment. I am in search on tht code where user pays on website only